# How can one make the Windows desktop the default location to save documents and pictures?

Tags: windows, default-settings

How can one bypass the Documents and Pictures default directories so that these item types are saved to the desktop instead? Note I do *not* want to simply move these *directories* to the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select Documents or Pictures folrder, right-click select Properties
2. Click Location tab. Enter the new folder. Click OK

Comment: +1, This trick will work on any folder, not only Documents/Pictures. To clarify more, you can edit, and tell to set location to `%Userprofile%\Desktop\ ` so the OP and future readers move in right direction.